# How to hide, fade in and fade out div with jQuery and keyboard controls?

Tags: jquery, hide, keyboard-shortcuts, fadein, fadeout

I'm wanting to show and hide a div using keyboard controls, specifically the required functionality is:

- hide div on page load
- fade in div when doing key combination (either
  `ctrl + shift + i` or `f + i`)
- fade out div when doing key
  combination (either `ctrl + shift + o` or `f + o`)

I was working with:

http://www.michaelckennedy.net/Samples/blog/HotKeys/

But it doesn't seem to work with Firefox.

I am now attempting to use:

https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/

Which has a detailed README here:

https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty/blob/master/README-DETAILED.md

I am not familiar with jQuery terminology however and therefore can't quite figure out how to implement the required functionality.

My first attempt was:

```
<script src="js/jwerty.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myDiv").hide();
});

jwerty.key('f+i', function () {
$("#myDiv").fadeIn(400);
});

jwerty.key('f+o', function () { 
$("#myDiv").fadeOut(400);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution:** use a comma between letters.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myDiv").hide();
});

jwerty.key('f,i', function () {
$("#myDiv").fadeIn(400);
});

jwerty.key('f,o', function () { 
$("#myDiv").fadeOut(400);
});
</script>
```